# brace expansion together with non permuting lists {txtfile,index}{1..3}.{txt,html} I want `{txtfile,index}` to correspond with `{txt,html}`

Tags: bash, shell, brace-expansion

`{txtfile,index}{1..3}.{txt,html}`
I want `{txtfile,index}` to correspond with `{txt,html}`
to produce:
`txtfile1.txt`
`txtfile2.txt`
`txtfile3.txt`
`index1.html`
`index2.html`
`index3.html`

but this code will generate all possible combinations
I don't want `txtfile1.html` or `index1.txt`
so the below doesn't work..
`{txtfile,index}{1..3}.{txt,html}`

I just thought corresponding lists expansion would be nice (their use case is almost always coupled with brace expansion)
syntax could be : `{txtfile:index}{1..3}.{txt:html}`
since we only need this feature for lists of length 2 or more, there will always be `:` so we know it's a corresponding list

here is a very *long* solution using for loops and *3* lines..
note: this solution is unusable for fast manual file creation

```bsh
fileNames=(txtfile index)
fileExtensions=(txt html)
for i in ${!fileNames[@]}; do echo ${fileNames[$i]}{1..3}.${fileExtensions[$i]}; done
```

one line for copy paste: `fileNames=(txtfile index); fileExtensions=(txt html); for i in ${!fileNames[@]}; do echo ${fileNames[$i]}{1..3}.${fileExtensions[$i]}; done`

even this is bad, it does 2 `echo`, so 2 lines.. (it still works if all I want to do it `touch` create files)

```
txtfile1.txt txtfile2.txt txtfile3.txt
index1.html index2.html index3.html
```

Answer (score 3):

You're overengineering this:

```
txtfile{1..3}.txt index{1..3}.html
```

is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

The list

```
txtfile1.txt
txtfile2.txt
txtfile3.txt
index1.html
index2.html
index3.html
```

may be generated using the following *two* brace expansions:

```
txtfile{1..3}.txt
index{1..3}.html
```

Example:

```bsh
$ printf '%s\n' txtfile{1..3}.txt index{1..3}.html
txtfile1.txt
txtfile2.txt
txtfile3.txt
index1.html
index2.html
index3.html
```

You could possibly write that as the single brace expansion

```
{txtfile{1..3}.txt,index{1..3}.html}
```

but you don't gain anything from that.